# How to apply bearer token with a get?

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I'm trying to access an API that requires a bearer token. I am able to get the bearer token, but I do not understand the next steps. The token is required in the header, but a get only accepts 2 parameters which would be my url and parameters?

I have been trying to mimic the companies javascript example. https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKUxM.jpg
https://portal.trafnet.com/rest/home/JavascriptExample
https://portal.trafnet.com/rest

```
#Urls
tokenurl = 'https://portal.trafnet.com/rest/token'

#Creds
user='test@test.com'
password='test'

#Fetch Bearer Token
tokenfetch = requests.post(tokenurl, data = {'grant_type':'password', 'username':user, 'password':password})
tokenval = tokenfetch.json()

mytoken = tokenval['access_token']
```

Below this line I obviously do not understand.

```
#DataParms
datefrom = '2019-09-01'
dateto = '2019-09-01'
sitecode = '01'
includeinternaloc = 'true'
datasummedbyday = 'false'



header = {'Authorization: Bearer %s' %mytoken}
params = {'SiteCode':sitecode, 'DateFrom':datefrom, 'DateTo':dateto,'IncludeInternalLocations':includeinternaloc, 'DataSummedByDay':datasummedbyday}
response = requests.post(dataurl,params,header)
print(response)
print(response.json())
```

{'Message': "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'https://portal.trafnet.com/rest/api/traffic'."}

Answer (score 0):

if i understand the problem correctly you have got a bearer token from the post request and have to use the same token in the next GET API call in the header. To pass the headers use headers as keyword argument to the requests.get method

One example of headers with bearer token: {'Authorization': 'Bearer <access_token>' }

```
requests.get(dataurl, params=params, headers=header)
```